# Can I use App Center with pnpm to build a React Native app?

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, pnpm

I am using App Center to build a React Native IOS app.

The app is contained within a monorepo which (currently) uses `npm` and its `workspaces` feature.

There is a desire to migrate from `npm` to `pnpm` but the installation in App Center appears to be fixed to use either `npm` or `yarn`. It appears to switch based on the presence of the appropriate lockfile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/react-native/ios/#51-yarn

> 5.1. Yarn
> Yarn is a faster, more deterministic replacement for npm. If a yarn.lock file is present in your repo next to package.json, then App Center will use Yarn, doing yarn install at the start of the build. Otherwise, it will do npm install.

This leaves me at a dead end. I cannot migrate to `pnpm` if App Center forces `npm`/`yarn`. Is there configuration I can add somewhere?

Comment: I have stuck at the same dead end.

Comment: @mununki I did not find a way of doing this with App Center and was actively moving away from it. Unfortunately the company shut down before it was completed.